# Calling external function on pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, size-reduction

I have a dataframe that looks like this: df

```
Index   timestamp       name latitude   longitude
0   2019-08-03 04:50:12 1   36.82454681 24.96810198
1   2019-08-03 04:50:20 1   36.82462692 24.96758223
2   2019-08-03 04:50:29 1   36.82474136 24.96686697
3   2019-08-03 04:50:40 1   36.82484436 24.96621704
4   2019-08-03 08:50:41 1   36.82494354 24.96556711
5   2019-08-03 08:50:42 1   36.82505035 24.96491718
6   2019-08-03 08:50:43 1   36.82514191 24.96433306
7   2019-08-03 04:50:44 1   36.82524872 24.9636879
8   2019-08-03 04:51:49 2   36.82555771 24.96175003
9   2019-08-03 04:52:00 2   36.82566833 24.96104002
10  2019-08-03 04:52:20 2   36.82586288 24.95981693
11  2019-08-03 04:52:30 2   36.82597733 24.95910788
```

I want to apply a function which I installed from pip (https://pypi.org/project/rdp/). It is used to reduce the number of points in a curve. When I do:

```
from rdp import rdp
RDP_out = rdp(df[['latitude','longitude']].to_numpy(),epsilon=0.00005)
```

It works for all points in the dataset. But, I want to apply the function rdp on the unique column values 'name' within a 3 hour window for all rows in the dataframe. Any idea how I do this?

Comment: You can find all unique values using `df.value_counts()` and actually get them into a list format using `df.value_counts().reset_index()` I think.
You can also look into `group_by`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html, and group_by name. Then, you can filter by time by convertime your `timestamp` object to an instance of a `datetime.datetime` object using Python's `datetime` library and extracting the `hour`, `minute` and `second` attributes from it.

Comment: @Jeoren post expected result. By unique value you mean one row from example `name = 1`?

Comment: I want to indeed groupby the 'name' column. The function should be applied in this case for all indices for name = 1 (not looking into the values of name=2). And then the function should be applied for name=2 (not looking into the values of name=1). I want to specify an extra parameter 'dt=3 hours'. In this case for name=1 the function should only be applied for the first 4 indices (they are within 3 hours) and indices 5-7 separately (they are also within 3 hours).

All names and timestamps are already sorted